# symfony2.7 FOS USER error on prod

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I just try to connect on my website using the app.php with

```
new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

and i got an error 500 when login and stay blocked on /login_check.
But if i change it to:

```
new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

its work with no problem!!

So i check the prod.log of symfony and here what i found:

```
[2015-06-24 13:47:11] php.CRITICAL: Fatal Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/crm/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__dmMembreBundleEntityMembreAuth.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') {"type":64,"file":"/var/www/html/crm/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php","line":209,"level":6143,"stack":[{"function":"getProxyDefinition","type":"->","class":"Doctrine\\Common\\Proxy\\AbstractProxyFactory","file":"/var/www/html/crm/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php","line":119,"args":[]},{"function":"getProxy","type":"->","class":"Doctrine\\Common\\Proxy\\AbstractProxyFactory","file":"/var/www/html/crm/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php","line":2677,"args":[]},{"function":"createEntity","type":"->","class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\UnitOfWork","file":"/var/www/html/crm/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SimpleObjectHydrator.php","line":138,"args":[]},{"function":"hydrateRowData","type":"->","class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\Internal\\Hydration\\SimpleObjectHydrator","file":"/var/www/html/crm/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SimpleObjectHydrator.php","line":48,"args":[]},{"function":"hydrateAllData","type":"->","class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\Internal\\Hydration\\SimpleObjectHydrator","file":"/var/www/html/crm/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/AbstractHydrator.php","line":140,"args":[]},{"function":"hydrateAll","type":"->","class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\Internal\\Hydration\\AbstractHydrator","file":"/var/www/html/crm/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php","line":756,"args":[]},{"function":"load","type":"->","class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\Persisters\\BasicEntityPersister","file":"/var/www/html/crm/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php","line":196,"args":[]},{"function":"findOneBy","type":"->","class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\EntityRepository","file":"/var/www/html/crm/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Doctrine/UserManager.php","line":68,"args":[]},{"function":"findUserBy","type":"->","class":"FOS\\UserBundle\\Doctrine\\UserManager","file":"/var/www/html/crm/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Model/UserManager.php","line":92,"args":[]},{"function":"findUserByUsername","type":"->","class":"FOS\\UserBundle\\Model\\UserManager","file":"/var/www/html/crm/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Model/UserManager.php","line":108,"args":[]},{"function":"findUserByUsernameOrEmail","type":"->","class":"FOS\\UserBundle\\Model\\UserManager","file":"/var/www/html/crm/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Security/EmailUserProvider.php","line":21,"args":[]},{"function":"findUser","type":"->","class":"FOS\\UserBundle\\Security\\EmailUserProvider","file":"/var/www/html/crm/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Security/UserProvider.php","line":45,"args":[]},{"function":"loadUserByUsername","type":"->","class":"FOS\\UserBundle\\Security\\UserProvider","file":"/var/www/html/crm/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php","line":83,"args":[]},{"function":"retrieveUser","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authentication\\Provider\\DaoAuthenticationProvider","file":"/var/www/html/crm/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php","line":70,"args":[]},{"function":"authenticate","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authentication\\Provider\\UserAuthenticationProvider","file":"/var/www/html/crm/app/cache/prod/classes.php","line":3077,"args":[]},{"function":"authenticate","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authentication\\AuthenticationProviderManager","file":"/var/www/html/crm/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener.php","line":96,"args":[]},{"function":"attemptAuthentication","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall\\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener","file":"/var/www/html/crm/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AbstractAuthenticationListener.php","line":146,"args":[]},{"function":"handle","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall\\AbstractAuthenticationListener","file":"/var/www/html/crm/app/cache/prod/classes.php","line":2992,"args":[]},{"function":"onKernelRequest","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall","file":"/var/www/html/crm/app/cache/prod/classes.php","line":2245,"args":[]},{"function":"call_user_func:{/var/www/html/crm/app/cache/prod/classes.php:2245}","file":"/var/www/html/crm/app/cache/prod/classes.php","line":2245,"args":[]},{"function":"doDispatch","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","file":"/var/www/html/crm/app/cache/prod/classes.php","line":2178,"args":[]},{"function":"dispatch","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher","file":"/var/www/html/crm/app/cache/prod/classes.php","line":2339,"args":[]},{"function":"dispatch","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher","file":"/var/www/html/crm/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":3083,"args":[]},{"function":"handleRaw","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","file":"/var/www/html/crm/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":3056,"args":[]},{"function":"handle","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","file":"/var/www/html/crm/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":3207,"args":[]},{"function":"handle","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerAwareHttpKernel","file":"/var/www/html/crm/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":2429,"args":[]},{"function":"handle","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","file":"/var/www/html/crm/web/app.php","line":28,"args":[]},{"function":"{main}","file":"/var/www/html/crm/web/app.php","line":0,"args":[]}]} []
[2015-06-24 13:47:11] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/crm/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__dmMembreBundleEntityMembreAuth.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')" at /var/www/html/crm/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php line 209 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 0): Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/crm/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__dmMembreBundleEntityMembreAuth.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') at /var/www/html/crm/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php:209)"} []
```

Off course i first think about chmod on my cache directory but evrything is on 777 recursivly... and working like a charm if i dont set the debug on false!

So if anyone have an idea...

Comment: `rm -rf app/cache/*; chmod -R 777 app/cache`

Comment: Thanks john Smith but i already try this and its not working on prod with debug on false.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer

Before go on prod, we need to warm the prod cache to completely delete so before delete of the cache folder we have to execute this command:

```
php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug
```

and after:

```
rm -rf app/cache/*; chmod -R 777 app/cache
```

And that's all folks!